# Php mysql regexp search for non nums instead of spaces

Tags: php, mysql, regex

```
SELECT object_nm FROM `objects` WHERE `object_nm` REGEXP '[^0-9]*Vasil[^0-9]*[^0-9]Levski[^0-9]*[^0-9]1[^0-9]*'
```

what i want is to search for 'Vasil levski 1' with only letters (any length) allowed between words.

Comment: "only letters allowed between words" doesn't make sense to me. Do you mean you want to search for 'Vasil' AND 'levski' AND '1' and only return results that have all three of those strings AND only have letters (no numbers OR spaces?) between words?

Comment: search for these words and allow only letters and spaces between words.

Comment: Would `VasilLevski1` be a valid match?

Comment: Yes, also Vasil sdfasdf Levski asdkjad 1 or VasillllLevskiiii1 is valid. But Vasil Levski 11 is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
^[[:alpha:] ]*Vasil[[:alpha:] ]*Levski[[:alpha:] ]*1[[:alpha:] ]*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^              # Start of string
[[:alpha:] ]*  # Any number of letters or spaces
Vasil          # Vasil
[[:alpha:] ]*  # Any number of letters or spaces
Levski         # etc.
[[:alpha:] ]*
1
[[:alpha:] ]*
$              # until end of string
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work as i perfectly. But it's a help. I will play with these regexp and post if/when i come to a solution. 10x very much.

Comment: it gives me about 10 founds and should give me over 400

Comment: @m4r71n: I have updated the regex according to your comment above.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, seems i didn't rewrote it right. 10x again.

Comment: i had an idea for even better results, may i ask u how to make it like:   ^ [[:alpha:] ]*WORD[[:alpha:] ]?[:anything:][[:alpha:] ]?WORD[[:alpha:] ]*
$

Comment: `.*` means "anything". But I don't see how that leads to better results.

Comment: because it would be best if i forbit only one character before and after each word  ex:  if search levski 1 -> levski 11(wrong) but levski 1 floor 14 (right)

Comment: and now i realise it'd be better to work with [^:digit] instead of [:alpha:] because there might be special characters.